# React locator example

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I am trying to understand how the react selectors are working according to https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#react-selectors . So I am trying some things in playwright sandbox. Seems that the react component cannot be found.

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Job/qa-engineer-jobs-SRCH_KO0,11.htm")
    page.locator("_react=q[key='1007467366491']").click()
    browser.close()
```

Error:

```
    playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "_react=q[key='1007467366491']"
============================================================
```

[sandbox example](https://try.playwright.tech/?l=python&s=x3o4rfm)

Are there any more detailed examples for react out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playwright does not support key filtering at the moment. But you can filter for the `job.id` which is part of the `props`:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Job/qa-engineer-jobs-SRCH_KO0,11.htm")
    page.locator("_react=q[job.id=1007630619432]").click()
    browser.close()
```

Comment: Hi, i have a playwright python issue.  There isn't much responses and quality documentation for Playwright Python. i'd appreciate if you can take a look over it, here is the link to the issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71631162/playwright-python-tab-link-not-visible    , thanks