# Playwright Python - Tab Link Not Visible

Tags: python, html, css, playwright, playwright-python

I am trying to hover the Mouse Pointer over the Tab Link "Markets". But inside Playwright it states the element is not visible. I have tried to use page.wait_for_selector, but i get the same type of response. I have tried multiple ways in using the Xpath and CSS Selector, but none of them are working. Below is the Python Code, the ways i have written the Xpaths, and CSS Selectors, and than finally the HTML Code.

```
markets_tab = page.query_selector('//*[@id="sections-scroll-target"]/ul/ul/li[8]/a')
    
page.wait_for_selector(markets_tab, timeout=10000)

page.hover(markets_tab)

page.wait_for_timeout(10000)
```

Below are the Different ways i have written and used the Xpath and CSS Selector. I get the same results with all of them. The first two Xpaths are from right clicking and selecting Xpath, and the Xpath to website link is what i adjusted and wrote. Also CSS Selector below is also from right clicking and copying.

```
# Xpath
'//*[@id="sections-scroll-target"]/ul/ul/li[8]/a'

# Full Xpath
'//html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/header/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/ul/li[8]/a' 

# Xpath to tab website link 
'//*[@href= "https://www.testdummysite.com/news/markets?mod=nav_left_section" ]'

# CSS Selector
'#sections-scroll-target > ul > ul > li:nth-child(8) > a'
```

Below is the HTML Code that is obtained from "right click" - "inspect". The Tab Link "Markets" is under a List Item Element Tag (li). There are a total of 18 Menu Tab Links, the "Markets" tab link is in the 8th order of List Item Element tag. Below is the HTM Code of the List Item Element Tags, the opened List Item Element tag with the "a-tag" is the one containing the "Markets" Tab Link,

```
<li class="style--subsection-item--ICtfMGEX "><a class="style--subsection-link--z3fnuRxn " tabindex="0" href="https://www.testdummysite.com/?mod=nav_left_section">Home</a></li>
<li class="style--subsection-item--ICtfMGEX "><a class="style--subsection-link--z3fnuRxn " tabindex="0" href="https://www.testdummysite.com/?mod=nav_left_section">Jogging</a></li>
<li class="style--subsection-item--ICtfMGEX "><a class="style--subsection-link--z3fnuRxn " tabindex="0" href="https://www.testdummysite.com/?mod=nav_left_section">Tennis</a></li>
<li class="style--subsection-item--ICtfMGEX "><a class="style--subsection-link--z3fnuRxn " tabindex="0" href="https://www.testdummysite.com/?mod=nav_left_section">Soccer</a></li>
<li class="style--subsection-item--ICtfMGEX "><a class="style--subsection-link--z3fnuRxn " tabindex="0" href="https://www.testdummysite.com/?mod=nav_left_section">Basketball</a></li>
<li class="style--subsection-item--ICtfMGEX "><a class="style--subsection-link--z3fnuRxn " tabindex="0" href="https://www.testdummysite.com/?mod=nav_left_section">Sports</a></li>
<li class="style--subsection-item--ICtfMGEX "><a class="style--subsection-link--z3fnuRxn " tabindex="0" href="https://www.testdummysite.com/?mod=nav_left_section">Tech</a></li>
<li class="style--subsection-item--ICtfMGEX "><a class="style--subsection-link--z3fnuRxn " tabindex="0" href="https://www.testdummysite.com/?mod=nav_left_section">Markets</a></li>
  <a class="style--subsection-link--z3fnuRxn " tabindex="0" href="https://www.testdummysite.com/news/markets?mod=nav_left_section">Markets</a>
```

Below is the Error Response i get when trying to make the element visible by using the page.wait_for_selector()

```
TypeError: click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'selector'
```

Comment: The problem is, your question is not clear - you need to say exactly which `<a>` you are trying to hover, because in one xpath you target the one inside `<li>` no 8, and in another you target the href of the last line (the line that is indented but should not be).

Comment: Both of these have "Markets", so which is it?

Comment: Both of them are the same, they both are for the "Markets" link.  the Xpaths including <li>No 8 is for the Markets Link. one is the Xpath, the other is the Full Xpath. both of them are for the Markets Link.   As stated in the description, i'am trying to hover over the "Markets" tab link.  They are not different, they are the same. Just one X Path Version, another Full Xpath Version, and the other  a-tag href Version.  the different paths i provided was for note purpsoes displaying that i have used all of them.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, you should use a string as selector.

[page.waitForSelector(selector[, options])](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector)

> selector `<string>` A selector to to query for

[page.click(selector[, options])](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-click)

> selector  A selector to search for an element

```js
selector = '//*[@id="sections-scroll-target"]/ul/ul/li[8]/a'
    
page.wait_for_selector(selector, timeout=10000)

page.hover(selector)
```

---

Looks like you want `https://www.testdummysite.com/news/markets?mod=nav_left_section`

If so this will work

```js
//*[@href= "https://www.testdummysite.com/news/markets?mod=nav_left_section" ]
```

but these get a different link `https://www.testdummysite.com/?mod=nav_left_section`.

```js
//*[@id="sections-scroll-target"]/ul/ul/li[8]/a

#sections-scroll-target > ul > ul > li:nth-child(8) > a
```

Because these URLs are similar, I wonder if you've posted the HTML accurately?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i still get similar error as not being visible. the error states "waiting for selector "//*[@id="sections-scroll-target"]/ul/ul/li[8]/a" to be visible ". Also there was slight typo, i edited the page.click( ) to page.hover( ), page.hover( ) is how you would hover the mouse over the tab, page.click() is for clicking. But the edit didn't matter, it would give same result anyway for page.click() or page.hover(), i get the same error result.

Comment: At least you know that `page.wait_for_selector()` does not make the element visible, need something else. I can't see the usual attributes like `display: none` on the element. Is there an overlay on the page?

Comment: when you say overlay, are you meaning like a pop up that appears on the page ? if so, the anser is no, there is no pop up that appears.

Comment: the wbsite link Xpath '//*[@href= "https://www.testdummysite.com/news/markets?mod=nav_left_section" ]'   i already tried this before posting this question and stated in the description it did not work.  when you are referring in that 2 URLS are similar, which ones are you talking about ? From what i looked, the HTML is correct, i copied and pasted them.